# Getting Error CS1504 Source file 'C:\temp\dashboard\ in VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I got an old solution from a friend. It ran on .NET Framework 2.0. Now I have windows 10 and VS 2017. But when I try to open the project and run it I get the following error:

```
CS1504 Source file 'C:\temp\dashboard\
```

This is the exact error I am getting. It does not specify what file, and it doesn't close the apostrophe either. Strange. In the output, I get this

```
1>CSC : error CS1504: Source file 'C:\temp\dashboard\========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any idea what could be wrong here? CS1504 error is related to [some file cannot be read by the compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1504), but that doesn't specify any file.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this in the end?